# Report scheduling in Jasper Server

Tags: jasperserver

How to setup a report schedule in Jasper server 5.0 to run every 2 hours, from 8:00 AM to 8:00 PM every day excepting Saturdays? In other words - the schedule has to start at 8:00 AM, runs every 2 hours and stops at 8:00 PM for every day, excepting Saturdays.

Comment: [CronTrigger Tutorial](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-1.x/tutorials/crontrigger)

Answer (score 0):

The hours input box should be filled as 8,10,12,14,16,18,20